# Joining a table to itself in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

Very confused by this one.

I'm trying to join a table to itself. I have the following details:

```
PRODUCT NO           FORMAT NO             FORMAT CODE              NUMBER
1000                 1111                  P                        0
1000                 1112                  O                        0
1000                 1113                  H                        546
```

I want to create a SELECT statement that outputs all the "O" format codes, but rather than outputting "0" in the "NUMBER" column, I want to output "546". It would look like this:

```
PRODUCT NO           FORMAT NO             FORMAT CODE              NUMBER
1000                 1112                  O                        546
```

So I think here I'm effectively joining the table to itself? Just not sure how to do this...

Thanks!

Comment: How would one know that the value `546` is to be matched to that `O` record?

Comment: Basically H is the only format code where the NUMBER column is populated. For all other format codes, the NUMBER = 0.

Comment: And what happens when other NUMBERs are populated?

Comment: Do you mean that if the O value is zero, you want to show the H value for the same product number instead? So you want to self-join and use a decode/case to decide which value to show? And always H - is P relevant at all?

Comment: Alex Poole, thanks this is what I am looking for. P probably isn't relevant in this scenario actually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from what has been stated above that you want something like this:

```
SELECT p1.product_no, p1.format_no, p1.format_code, p2.h_number
  FROM myproducts p1 INNER JOIN myproducts p2
    ON p1.product_no = p2.product_no
   AND p1.format_code <> p2.format_code
   AND p2.format_code = 'H'
 WHERE p1.format_code = 'O';
```

I have to add editorially that I think this design is a bit weird and I'm not sure one could call it "normalized."

Answer (score 3):

Always keep it simple, use all available Oracle built-in features.

```
SELECT * FROM
(     
 SELECT FORMAT_NO, FORMAT_CODE, SEQ
  , (CASE WHEN FORMAT_CODE = 'O' THEN LAG(seq, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY FORMAT_CODE) END) nn_seq
FROM 
(                           
SELECT 1000 PRODUCT_NO, 1111 FORMAT_NO, 'P' FORMAT_CODE, 0 SEQ FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 1000, 1112, 'O', 0 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 1000, 1113, 'H', 546 FROM dual
)
ORDER BY 2
)
WHERE FORMAT_CODE = 'O'
```

/

Output:
    1112    O   0   546

In above query you need to perform ordering first then use Oracle built in LAG() or LEAD() depending on order and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

From comments it seems to want to use the H value only when the O value is zero:

```
select t1.product_no, t1.format_no, t1.format_code,
  case when t1.value = 0 then t2.value else t1.value end as value
from your_table t1
join your_table t2
on t2.product_no = t1.product_no
where t1.format_code = 'O'
and t2.format_code = 'H';

PRODUCT_NO  FORMAT_NO FORMAT_CODE      VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
      1000       1112 O                  546
```

You could also use lead/lag rather than a self-join, as Art suggested, if you can identify a coherent ordering for the format codes or format numbers. If you restrict the inner query to just the two code O and H the lag is simple:

```
select product_no, format_no, format_code, value,
  lag(value) over (partition by product_no order by format_code) as next_code
from your_table
where format_code in ('O', 'H');

PRODUCT_NO  FORMAT_NO FORMAT_CODE      VALUE  NEXT_CODE
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
      1000       1113 H                  546            
      1000       1112 O                    0        546
```

And then you can use that as an inner query, using coalesce again (or decode if you prefer) to replace a zero value, and discarding the H rows:

```
select product_no, format_no, format_code,
  case when value = 0 then next_value else value end as value
from (
  select product_no, format_no, format_code, value,
    lag(value) over (partition by product_no order by format_code) as next_value
  from your_table
  where format_code in ('O', 'H')
)
where format_code = 'O';

PRODUCT_NO  FORMAT_NO FORMAT_CODE      VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
      1000       1112 O                  546
```

This may look more complicated but it only hits the table once.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11fcc/1).

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to get you what you want with this data, but I doubt it works in the general case:

```
SELECT "PRODUCT NO", "FORMAT NO", "FORMAT CODE", MAX(NUMBER) AS NUMBER
FROM T
WHERE "FORMAT CODE" = 'O'
GROUP BY "PRODUCT NO", "FORMAT NO", "FORMAT CODE"
```

Based on the slim information you've shared I might also guess this. But I still suspect it's wrong:

```
SELECT "PRODUCT NO", "FORMAT NO", "FORMAT CODE",
    CASE WHEN NUMBER <> 0 THEN NUMBER ELSE (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM T) END AS NUMBER
FROM T
WHERE "FORMAT CODE" = 'O'
```

Or this:

```
SELECT "PRODUCT NO", "FORMAT NO", "FORMAT CODE",
    CASE
        WHEN NUMBER <> 0 THEN NUMBER
        ELSE
            (
            SELECT NUMBER FROM T as t2
            WHERE
                    t2."PRODUCT NO" = t1."PRODUCT NO"
                AND t2."FORMAT CODE" = 'H'
            )
    END AS NUMBER
FROM T as t1
WHERE "FORMAT CODE" = 'O'
```