# Using a subquery in SELECT clause with a join of a table to itself

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

Trying to create a subquery in the SELECT clause (using Oracle 11g). The subquery includes a join of a table to itself. I'm getting an "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" error message (my worst enemy...). Here's my code:

```
SELECT e.ISBN,
(SELECT p2.PAGE_NUMBERS FROM PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p1 INNER JOIN PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p2
    ON p1.TITLE_CODE = p2.TITLE_CODE
    AND p2.FORMAT_CODE = 'HB'
    WHERE p1.FORMAT_CODE = 'OC') AS "Page Numbers"
    FROM ISBN_TABLE e
```

Hope this makes sense, I can clarify further on what I am looking to do here if it doesn't make sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem is that subquery is returning more than one row for each original query row. To fix this problem you can use max(p2.PAGE_NUMBERS) in the subquery, this will remove the error, but will not give you the result you are expecting, so, if you tell us what you exactly want to do, maybe we could help you

Comment: Ah, I see - yes, adding MAX gives me "6496" for all rows, I'm assuming this is the maximum value in the entire dataset. I've explained on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612074/joining-a-table-to-itself-in-oracle when I was looking to build the original query, which I am now trying to nest as a subquery within a select statement. Let me know if I should clarify further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, assuming that your subquery returns one row for every isbn row, that you haven't included a correlation between the isbn table and your subquery.

You should do something like (guessing here, since we don't know your table structures):

```
SELECT e.ISBN,
(SELECT p2.PAGE_NUMBERS FROM PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p1 INNER JOIN PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p2
    ON p1.TITLE_CODE = p2.TITLE_CODE
    AND p2.FORMAT_CODE = 'HB'
    WHERE p1.FORMAT_CODE = 'OC'
    and    e.title_code = p1.title_code -- change this to whatever condition correlates the table and subquery!
    ) AS "Page Numbers"
    FROM ISBN_TABLE e
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite this as a join and put the subquery in the from clause, along with the join conditions, eg. soemthing like:

```
SELECT e.ISBN,
       pg.page_numbers AS "Page Numbers"
FROM   ISBN_TABLE e
       inner join (SELECT p2.PAGE_NUMBERS,
                          p1.title_code -- don't forget to include the join column(s)!
                   FROM   PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p1
                          INNER JOIN PAGE_NUMBERS_TABLE p2
                            ON p1.TITLE_CODE = p2.TITLE_CODE
                   AND    p2.FORMAT_CODE = 'HB'
                   WHERE  p1.FORMAT_CODE = 'OC') pg
         on (e.title_code = pg.title_code) -- or whatever the join condition is
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, the correlation issue you described resolved it (the way you described it e.title_code = p1.title_code was exact)!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is selecting a column value using a query.

```
select column1,
       (select some value from table where..) column2
from table
```

You have to make sure that the query

```
(select some value from table where..)
```

returns at most 1 row. If it returns more than 1 row you get the ora-01427 exception.